# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')

Tags: javascript

Делаю плавную прокрутку страницы, консоль выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBoundingClientRect'). Подскажите в чем проблема? Спасибо

```js
const body = document.body,
jsScroll = document.getElementsByClassName('.page')[0],
height = jsScroll.getBoundingClientRect().height - 1,
speed = 0.05

var offset = 0

body.style.height = Math.floor(height) + "px"

function smoothScroll() {
offset += (window.scrollY - offset) * speed

var scroll = "translateY(-" + offset + "px) translateZ(0)"
jsScroll.style.transform = scroll

raf = requestAnimationFrame(smoothScroll)
}
smoothScroll()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего надо дождаться загрузки страницы и только после этого вызывать функцию клика. Для этого можно воспользоваться событием [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    ... тут код
});
```

т.к. изначально при вызове `getBoundingClientRect`  на странице ещё не успел появится элемент `.page`